# Trying to jun java -cp my-jar.jar org.test.MyClass but it can't find class

Tags: java

I have a project that I compile to a fat jar (includes dependencies). I also have a class like this...

```
package com.me;
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Working");
    }
}
```

If I open up my jar I see the class file, however, when I run...

```
java -cp my-jar.jar com.me.MyClass
```

I get the following error...

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.me.MyClass
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.MyClass

Why is it not getting on the classpath? What is the proper way to run this?

I am on Windows so this may be a difference.

### Update

I have the following code to make it a fat jar in my build.gradle...

```
task fatJarTest(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-test-all'
    from sourceSets.test.output
    from {
       configurations.testCompile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
    with jar
}
```

When I comment out

```
from {
    configurations.testCompile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
}
```

And recreate the jar then everything works correctly but then it isn't a fat jar.

Comment: Is the class actually in `com/me/MyClass.class` in your jar? The folder structure matters. Also, `com.me.MyClass` **or** `org.test.MyClass`? Double check.

Comment: yeah it is in the correct folder IE from the root /com/me/MyClass.class

Comment: Looks like things are getting added to the Jar 2x (dependencies but MyClass is only in there once and looks fine). I will try a couple of other things to see if I can figure out what is happening.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch added updates

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to conflicting dependencies I had to add the following to my Build.gradle...

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'){
        exclude group: "org.ow2.asm", module: "asm"
    }
}
task fatJarTest(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-test-all'
    from {
       configurations.testCompile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }{
        exclude "META-INF/*"
        exclude "META-INF/*.*"
        exclude "META-INF/**/*.*"
        exclude "LICENSE.txt"
    }
    from sourceSets.test.output
    with jar
}
```

Basically this was one issue (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7934) and the other was META-INF squashing each other.